# Youtube Data API - How do you 'read' content items in your subscriptions list?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When I use the subscriptions.list api, the contentDetails.newItemCount fields always return the same number as before.

According the the docs, contentDetails.newItemCount refers to The number of new items in the subscription since its content was last read.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions

How can the content be "read" using the api so that the newItemCount becomes 0?

Comment: What number does it returns?  If you query the request, it should return 0. If this was not the case, it could be a bug.

Comment: subscriptions.list returns different numbers for each channel I'm subscribed to, and it returns the same numbers each time. So, simply using that request alone is not considered "reading" the content. I'm trying to figure out what is, and if it can be done using the API.

Comment: I've noticed that when I view a channel's home page on youtube in a browser, while logged in with the account that uses the API, the newItemCount for that channel becomes 0. I still don't know how to do accomplish that without using the API though.